# How to apply a hover effect to a single component present in react-table's row. Though there are multiple columns

Tags: reactjs, hover, mousehover, react-table

```
{
                id: "checkbox",
                accessor: "",
                Cell: ({ original }) => {
                  return (
                    <Checkbox
                      className="checkbox"
                      color={"#4caf50"}
                      onChange={() => this.toggleRow(original.id)}
                      checked={this.state.selected[original.id] === true}
                    />
                  );
                },
                Header: x => {
                  return (
                    <Checkbox
                      className="checkbox"
                      color={"#4caf50"}
                      onChange={() => this.toggleSelectAll()}
                      checked={this.state.selectAll === 1}
                    />
                  );
                },
                sortable: false,
                width: 45
              },
```

Here is the checkbox column code in react-table but I want to show the checkbox for the specific row on which mouse is hovered, otherwise it the other rows should contain images instead of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's practical to use jQuery. 
First of all, `npm i jquery`
In React imports, add `import $ from 'jquery'` and inside `componentDidMount()` function add the code, similar to this:
When a mouse is hovered over a column element, add a checkbox class to it. When done, remove class.
Classes are added through `$("#id").addClass("class-name")` and removed with `$("#id").removeClass("class-name")`